# JavaFX Dialog: Run onClosingRequest only when Ok button pressed

Tags: java, javafx

I have a form Dialog and I want to add a confirmation alert before the dialog closes.

The dialog is not to close until confirmed Ok.
This I can prevent by consuming the event.

It should only confirm on clicking the Dialog Ok, not on Cancel.
Problem is, I cannot see which button was clicked on the event. So the Alert confirmation is shown for both OK and CANCEL buttons on the dialog.

How can I prevent the onClosingReqeust for cancel button?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;

public class DialogTestApplication extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    class MyDialog extends Dialog<ButtonType> {

        public MyDialog(Window window) {
            setTitle("MyDialog");
            initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            initOwner(window);
            setResizable(true);

            GridPane contentPane = new GridPane();
            contentPane.add(new TextField(), 0, 0);
            getDialogPane().setContent(contentPane);

            getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.OK, ButtonType.CANCEL);

            setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
                alert.showAndWait().ifPresent(response -> {
                    if (response == ButtonType.CANCEL) {
                        event.consume();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final StackPane root = new StackPane();
        final Label rootLabel = new Label("DialogTestApplication");
        root.getChildren().add(rootLabel);
        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("DialogTestApplication");
        primaryStage.show();

        Platform.setImplicitExit(true);
        MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(primaryStage);
        dialog.showAndWait().ifPresent(response -> {
            if (response == ButtonType.OK) {
                System.out.println("OK");
            }
            Platform.exit();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the Dialog Javadoc I found a solution that works.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html

```
Button button = (Button) getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK);

button.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, event -> {
    final Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.initOwner(window);
    alert.showAndWait().ifPresent(response -> {
        if (response == ButtonType.CANCEL) {
            event.consume();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
final Button btnCancel = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton( ButtonType.CANCEL);
    btnCancel.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, event -> {
    // handle cancel button code here
    event.consume();     
});

public boolean displayDialog() {
    Optional<ButtonType> result = dialog.showAndWait();
    if(result.get().getText().equals("Ok")) {
        //handle OK action. The dialog panel will close automatically.
    }
    return true;
}
```

Handle the cancel button event when instantiating the alert. The `event.consume()` method will prevent the alert dialog from closing when pressing `CANCEL`. You can add a method to display your alert, within that method handle the OK action.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle action event of the OK button instead of handling close request of the dialog. Something like this

```
    // I tested with onMouseClicked but the event doesn't get fired
    // onAction on the other hand works normally but we need to cast the node to a button
    Button button = (Button) getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK);

    button.setOnAction(e -> {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);

            alert.showAndWait().ifPresent(response -> {
                if (response == ButtonType.CANCEL) {
                    event.consume();
                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: I have tried that, did not work. The Alert Confirmation dialog that pops up when clicking OK becomes gray and unresponsive. Can only close the alert window, but its content is not visible.